# Como limpar as properties do neo4j depois de deletado todos os dados?

Tags: grafo, neo4j

Estava fazendo uns teste com o neo4j e de repende me vi diante de muitos nós e então resolvi limpar tudo, para poder começar a trabalhar com uma aplicação.
Então executei o seguinte comando:

```
match ( n ) detach delete n
```

Ele então limpou todos os nós que eu tinha , como o esperado!! A questão é que ficaram na aba

> Database Information no campo Property Keys

Umas tags que eu havia usado anteriormente!! Como posso removê las?

Aqui esta uma imagem de como ficou apos eu remover todos os nós:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de remover tudo que esta circulado com  vermelho.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve ser capaz de limpar tudo por:

- Parar o seu banco de dados Neo4j
- Excluindo dodos os dados correspondentes / graph.db / * (procure dentro da pasta graph.db)
- Reativar o banco de dados

Comment: Obrigado , em breve vou fazer o que diz  aqui em sua resposta.

Comment: De nada ;) é sempre bom ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

[Este é o link do manual do Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-remove-properties-using-empty-map) onde é ensinado a como remover todas as propriedades.

No manual diz que diferente da exclusão dos nodes e relações, não é possível excluir todas as propriedades de todos os nodes de uma só vez, porém, para remover todas as propriedades de um node você poderia usar o seguinte comando:

```
MATCH (p { name: 'Peter' })
SET p = { }
```

A grosso modo você estaria substituindo todas a propriedades de `p` por nada, ou seja, excluindo aquelas propriedades.

No seu caso, se você já excluiu todos os nodes, basta vc reiniciar o banco pois as propriedades só existem se existir um node, assim, quando vc reinicar o banco todas as propriedades cujos nodes foram excluidos também vão sumir.